# What does "cannot find lSDL" mean?

Tags: command-line, compiling

I am trying to install a software called DiSperSE. For that I am supposed to enter

> make install

When I enter this, terminal returns an error

```
Linking CXX executable fieldconv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/mse/fieldconv] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/mse/CMakeFiles/fieldconv.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does any one know what this mean? I tried to search what this lSDL is, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

-lSDL means your compiler wants to include the library for SDL you can install that by:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl*
```